# Call user class array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, class, command-line-arguments

How can I instantiate a class with an array of arguments in PHP?

**Normally** it would be `call_user_func_array` with functions but I need to instantiate a class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with [the reflection api](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) and in particular [ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php):

```
$class_name = 'fooBar';
$class_args = array('foo', 'bar');
$reflected_class = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
$class_instance = $reflected_class->newInstanceArgs($class_args);
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the PHP Manual on [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), you can still use it with objects.

I'm not sure how you are using these arguments, so I'll only give a simple example (sort of).

```
<?php

    class foo
    {
        public function concat()
        {
            $args = func_get_args();
            $output = '';

            if( count( $args ) > 0 )
            {
                foreach( $args as $value )
                {
                    $output .= $value;
                }
            }
            echo $output;
        }
    }

    $class = new foo();

    // Should Echo "Hello"
    call_user_func_array( array( $class, "concat" ), array( "H", "e", "l", "l", "o" ) );
```

Let me know if I'm missing any requirements you haven't mentioned. You should give examples of what you are trying to achieve (input/output, what function this is calling, etc).

Comment: Question is about instantiating an object, not calling its method.

Comment: Roger that. Go with Lepidosteus.